# Stretch row vector in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, stretch

I need to double the size of my vector like this:

```
x=[1 1 0 1 0 0 1]
```

to

```
x=[1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
```

Is there a simple way to do this without a loop?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: because I would rather use matrix manipulation because it is generally faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by:

```
x=[1 1 0 1 0 0 1];
y=[x;x];
x = y(:)';
```